# Change href after Javascript loads elements with its own data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Facebook Embedded posts on my website, and I am trying to change a specific attribute, but failing.

```
    <a class="_6j_ _5cix" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;J&quot;}" href="/sharer.php?s=2&amp;appid=2305272732&amp;p%5B0%5D=191027189287&amp;p%5B1%5D=1073742637&amp;share_source_type=unknown" target="_blank" title="Share this item" data-reactid=".r[3suu5].[1].[2]"><i class="_6k1 _528f" data-reactid=".r[3suu5].[1].[2].[0]"></i><span data-reactid=".r[3suu5].[1].[2].[1]">Share</span></a>
```

So first of all, I need to know how to access that class name.  The attribute I am trying to change is the href.  I also would like to remove "data-reactid=".r[3suu5].[1].[2]" as this is affecting how it works.

I think I know the code to use to change/remove attributes, the problem I think is I am running it too early as nothing changes.  Also, I can go on to Javascript console on google chrome and delete/change things and it works perfectly, I just need it to happen automatically.

Thanks,
Gavin.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByClassName("someClassName")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) or [`document.querySelector(".someClassName")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) ?

Comment: Is the class name "_6j_ _5cix" valid.  That is how it is shown on Javascript console, but I thought it couldn't have spaces.  Also, I know how to access class names but how do I get this to run after the Element has loaded, this is loaded via Javascript.

Comment: posts are likely added asynchronously...you could use setInterval to check for existence then clear the interval once found

Comment: @GavinMcBride The space between classes means that there are multiple classes on this element: `_6j_` and `_5cix`.

Comment: So to confirm, if I was using document.getElementsByClassName how would I write it to change the href?

Comment: It's mean that element have 2 class first `_6j_` and second `_5cix`. and you can add [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) ([onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)) event to check if element is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, if anyone has a spare minute do they mind putting some code together in a new answer?

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to access the class for?  There are a multitude of ways to do the things that you want to do, and here are some examples.  If you elaborate on specifically what your goal is, then that can help narrow down some of the potential solutions.

This will access the class, remove the attribute data-reactid, and change the href

```
myFunction('a','whatever-link.html'); 

function myFunction(el,href) {
    var el = $(el),
        //accesses the class
        currentClass = el.attr('class');

    el.removeAttr('data-reactid');
    el.attr('href',href);
}
```

OR, this puts everything in a click event

```
$('a').click(function() {
     var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');

     $(this).removeAttr('data-reactid');
     $(this).attr('href','whatever-link.html');
});
```

OR, this is just a way to take the class of all links and put them in an array (if you want to do it for whatever reason)

```
var classes = [];

$('a').each(function() {
    classes.push($(this).attr('class'));  
});
```

You can also select a link by a class:

```
 $('._6j_ _cxwhatever_');
```

I suggest reading [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Hey this is great, I need it be assigned to the class 'class="_6j_ _5cix"' as there are many more <a> tags.  Correct me if wrong though.

Comment: Why?  If so, you can just do $('._6j_').attr('class','6j_5cix'), or $('._5cix').attr('class','whatever')

Comment: And, as a commenter up top mentioned, it is worth noting that the space between _6j_ and _5cix does in fact mean that there are two classes assigned to this element.

Comment: Is there any way I can discuss you working on my site to get this going, I can also explain in more detail what I need?

Comment: Sure, email me at joshua.a.beam@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks, I hit you up.